# How to group matched elements to process both at once?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm working on a school project and we have to use XML and XSLT to generate our HTML. My project is a family tree. I achieved to select the root persons, but now I want group married persons and process them both at once and not every one on its own.

At the moment I select every root person and then search for the married person and display them together. But as every one is processed on its own I get all results two times.

My Data looks like this:

```
<persons>
    <person id="1" marriedTo="2" father="0" mother="0">
        <name>Father</name>
    </person>
    <person id="2" marriedTo="1" father="0" mother="0">
        <name>Mother</name>
    </person>
    ....
</persons>
```

My xslt code:

```
<xsl:template match="/persons/person[@father='0' and @mother='0']">
    <div class="person">
         <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="person">
         <xsl:value-of select="key('couple',@marriedTo)/name"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there any way to get two elements and process them together? Maybe like

```
<div>
    <xsl:value-of select="person[0]/name"/>
</div>
<div>
    <xsl:value-of select="person[1]/name"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you use? It might help to show us some sample input and result data that contains duplicates and the result you want instead.

Comment: I'm free to use every version. Which one would you suggest?
There are no dublicates in the xml, my problem is that every element with no parents gets parsed and creates a div with his name and the name of the married person, so I get each pair of married persons two times. One Time its "Father Mother" and one time its "Mother Father". But I only need "Father Mother"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind whether you select the father or mother first, change your existing template to match only the `person` record where the `marriedTo` is greater than their `id`. And have a second template that matches the opposite that then ignores that person.

```
<xsl:template match="/persons/person[@father='0' and @mother='0'][@marriedTo &gt; @id]">
    <div class="person">
         <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="person">
         <xsl:value-of select="key('couple',@marriedTo)/name"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/persons/person[@father='0' and @mother='0'][@marriedTo &lt; @id]" />
```

Of course, you might need extra templates if one person in the couple does have a father or mother, but it should give you the general idea.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Really easy but haven't thought of.